# Why is colorbox not auto-adjusting the width?

Tags: colorbox

Why is colorbox not auto-adjusting the width? Instead it is showing a
horizontal scrollbar.

This is the `div` that is shown inside the model.

```
<div style="width:900px">
    <div style="float:left;width:640px;height:640px;text-
align:center;background-color:#666;">
        <img src="xyz.gif" alt="#" />
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;background-color:#eee;min-width:260px">
        Show buttons here that must show
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make sure that my colorbox model auto-expands to show 900px div
and no scrollbar?

The div is 708px witdth. Where is it getting this value from?

Another problem: 
The height is sometimes 34px, sometimes 600px+ even if I click the same link.

```
This is wrapping divs from firebug:
<div id="colorbox" class="" style="padding-bottom: 42px; padding-right: 42px; display: block; position: absolute; width: 708px; height: 542px; top: 0px; left: 337px;">
<div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 584px; width: 750px;">
<div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 542px;"></div>
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 708px; height: 542px;">
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="display: block; width: 708px; overflow: auto; height: 522px;">
```

Somehow the width of the parent divs are getting calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying a width of 640px.... change that to min-width and then it would be allowed to grow.

Comment: That didn't do it. I see all the container/parent divs have 700px total width instead of 900. Is it auto calculation by colorbox?

Comment: Could be - my suggestion would be to view the divs in Firebug, then you can see which values are being overridden and where.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the plugin sizes itself to the dimensions of the digital asset you are displaying with it. But this can be overriden.

Consult the plug-in doc-o and pay special attention to the Dimensions section (height, width, etc.) and consider specifying a value of 100%.

[ColoBox docs](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)